# Why buttons on main vew do not work when partial views are showing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a simple project for CRUD using ASP.NET Core MVC. Editing is using partial view. Editing itself is working, but as long as the partial view is showing, the button on the main view are not working, not even able to go into corresponding function. Where did I set something wrong? How should I solve this? Attached are all code snippets I think are related.

Cost.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CarpetWash.Models
{
    public class Cost
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public decimal? Expense { get; set; }
        public string? Item { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Location { get; set; }
        public string? Note { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CarpetWashContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CarpetWash.Models
{
    public class CarpetWashContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cost> Costs { get; set; }

        public CarpetWashContext(DbContextOptions<CarpetWashContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public CarpetWashContext()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

CarpetWashViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CarpetWash.Models
{
    public class CarpetWashViewModel
    {
        public List<Cost> Costs { get; set; }
        public Cost SelectedCost { get; set; }
        public string DisplayMode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cost.cshtml

```
@model CarpetWash.Models.CarpetWashViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <head>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tblCosts").DataTable({
                    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<h1>Costs</h1>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        @{
            if (Model.SelectedCost != null)
            {
                if (Model.DisplayMode == "ReadWrite")
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("EditCost", Model.SelectedCost);
                }

            }
            if (Model.DisplayMode == "WriteOnly")
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("InsertCost", new Earn());
            }

        }

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add New Cost" formaction= "/CarpetWash/newCost" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <table id="tblCosts" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Expense</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model.Costs != null)
                    { 
                        foreach (var item in Model.Costs)
                        {
                            if (Model.SelectedEarn != null)
                            {
                                if (item.Id == Model.SelectedCost.Id)
                                {
                                    @:<tr class=" SelectedItem">
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @:<tr>
                                }
                            }
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Expense)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary Edit" formaction="/CarpetWash/selectCost/@item.Id " /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary Delete" formaction="/CarpetWash/deleteCost/@item.Id" />
                                </td>
                            @:</tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
```

Partial View EditCost.cshtml

```
@model CarpetWash.Models.Cost

<h4>Cost</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="SelectCost">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @title = "Please input a date (i.e. 2020-07-01)" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Expense" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expense, new { @title = "Please input a string" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Expense" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Item" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item, new { @title = "Please input a string" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Item" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @title = "Please input a string" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location, new { @title = "Please input a string" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Note" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Note, new { @title = "Please input a string" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Note" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" formaction="/CarpetWash/updateCost/@Model.Id" />
                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn" formaction="/CarpetWash/cost" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

CarpetWashController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JiaCarpetWash.Common;
using JiaCarpetWash.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace CarpetWash.Controllers
{
    public class CarpetWashController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CarpetWashContext _context;
        private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _mySettings;
        private readonly string _dbConnectString;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _MemoryCache;


        public CarpetWashController(CarpetWashContext context, IOptions<AppSettings> mySettings, IMemoryCache memCache)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mySettings = mySettings;
            _dbConnectString = _mySettings.Value.DBConnectionString;
            _MemoryCache = memCache;
        }

        // GET: CarpetWashController
        public async Task<IActionResult> Cost()
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            model.Costs = await _context.Costs.ToListAsync();
            model.SelectedCost = null;
    
            return View(model);
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> SelectCost(int? id)
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            model.Costs = await _context.Costs.ToListAsync();

            var cost = await _context.Costs.FindAsync(id);
            if (cost == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            model.SelectedCost = cost;
            model.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";

            return View("Cost", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SelectCost(int id)
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            model.Costs = await _context.Costs.ToListAsync();

            var cost = await _context.Costs.FindAsync(id);
            if (cost == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            model.SelectedCost = cost;
            model.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";

            return View("Cost", model);
        }

        // GET: CarpetWashController/UpdateCost/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCost(int? id)
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var cost = await _context.Costs.FindAsync(id);
            if (cost == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            model.SelectedCost = cost;
            model.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";

            return View("Cost", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCost(int id, [Bind("Id,Date,Expense,Item,Description,Location,Note")] Cost cost)
        {
            if (id != cost.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            model.SelectedCost = cost;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.DisplayMode = "ReadOnly";
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(cost);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!_context.Costs.Any(e => e.Id == id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                model.SelectedCost = null;
            }
            else
            {
                model.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";
            }
            model.Costs = await _context.Costs.ToListAsync();

            return View("Cost", model);
        }

        // GET: CarpetWashController/DeleteCost/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var cost = await _context.Costs
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (cost == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View("Cost");
        }

        // POST: CarpetWashController/DeleteCost/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteCost")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCostConfirmed(int id)
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel model = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            var cost = await _context.Costs.FindAsync(id);
            if (cost != null)
            {
                DeleteCostById(id);
                _context.Costs.Remove(cost);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            model.Costs = await _context.Costs.ToListAsync();
            model.SelectedCost = null;
            model.DisplayMode = "ReadOnly";
            return View("Cost", model);
        }

        private void DeleteCostById(int id)
        {
            using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectString);
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RemoveCost", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your partial view includes a form,and in `Cost.cshtml` it also has a form.You put the partial view in a form,but you cannot nest forms.So you can move the partial outside the form.
Here is a demo worked:
CarpetWashController.cs:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Cost()
        {
            CarpetWashViewModel c = new CarpetWashViewModel();
            List<Cost> cs = new List<Cost> { new Cost { Id = 1, Item = "item1", Date = new DateTime(), Expense = 1, Description="d1", Note="n1", Location="l1"} };
            Cost c1 = new Cost { Id = 2, Item = "item2", Date = new DateTime(), Expense = 2, Description = "d2", Note = "n2", Location = "l2" };
            cs.Add(c1);
            c.SelectedCost = c1;
            c.Costs = cs;
            c.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";
            return View(c);
        }
        public IActionResult newCost() {
            return View("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult selectCost(int id)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        public IActionResult deleteCost(int id)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Cost.cshtml:

```
<div>

    <div>
        @if (Model.SelectedCost != null)
        {
            if (Model.DisplayMode == "ReadWrite")
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("EditCost", Model.SelectedCost);
            }

        }
    </div>
    <form method="post">




        <input type="submit" value="Add New Cost" formaction="/CarpetWash/newCost" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="1" />



        <div>
            <table id="tblCosts" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Expense</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary Edit" formaction="/CarpetWash/selectCost/1 " /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary Delete" formaction="/CarpetWash/deleteCost/1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

Result:
[image]